# Сколько коробок понадобится, чтобы вместить все вещи

Tags: python, алгоритм

Задача вместить некоторое количество вещей в коробки. В одну коробку можно вместить не более 2 вещей. Вещи заданы списком из чисел, обозначающих их вес. Максимальный вес, который можно положить в коробку задан вторым параметром.
То есть, если дано ([5, 1, 4, 2, 3], 6), то нам нужно 3 коробки, чтобы вместить все вещи, максимум по 6 кило в коробку (например вот так 1: 5+1, 2: 4+2, 3: 3). Решение у меня есть такое.
Но как решить с помощью O(NlogN)?

```
def count(t,x):
  
  newT = sorted(t[:])
  counter = 0

  while len(newT) > 0:
    i = 0
    weight = x - newT[i]
    sec = max((i for i in newT if i <= weight), default=0) 
    newT.remove(newT[i])
    if sec in newT: newT.remove(sec)
    counter += 1
  return counter
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
      print(count([7, 10, 6, 7, 8], 11)) #5
      print(count([5, 1, 4, 2, 3], 6)) #3
      print(count([1, 3, 5, 999999999, 10000000000, 1000000000], 10000000000)) #4
      print(count([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5)) #3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, получилось у меня вот такое решение в итоге

```
def countBoxes(items,weight):
  items.sort(reverse=True)
  n = len(items)
  boxCounter = 0
  small = n-1
  big = 0 
  while big <= small:
    boxCounter+=1
    if weight - items[big] >= items[small]:
      small -= 1
    big += 1

  return boxCounter
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая фраза - "Не знаешь как решить задачу - отсортируй данные"

Отсортировали по убыванию. O(nlogn)

Один индекс идёт слева, второй справа.

Для каждого большого веса (индекс слева) находим максимальный, который можно добавить (правый индекс идёт влево), если он есть, и делаем пару. O(n)